# Nuget restore command with target using msbuild 16 vs2019

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

We are using msbuild command to restore nuget but package is not restoring with jenkins build.please find the following command.

please suggest solutions.also please suggest if any other way to achive it.Thanks in advance.

Initially i updated package documentformat.openxml to 2.11.1 and the build is success but when i update the same package to 2.11.3 if has thrown following exception.After that i tried updating some other package also but not updated and thrown same kind of exception as below.Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please add your Jenkins Pipeline code and Errors that you are seeing after running build.

Comment: <Target Name="FullBuild">
    <Error Condition = "'$(GitRevision)'==''" Text = "Git Revision property not defined." />
 
    <CallTarget Targets="RESTOREPACKAGES" />
    <CallTarget Targets="UPDATEVERSION" />
    <CallTarget Targets="CLEAN" />
    <CallTarget Targets="BUILD" />
    <CallTarget Targets="RUNUNITTESTS" Condition = "'$(SkipUnitTests)' != 'true'" />
    <CallTarget Targets="STAGE" Condition = "'$(SkipUnitTests)' == 'true'" />
  </Target>

Comment: Errors are The type or namespace could not be found.

Comment: could you share a snippet of console output?

Comment: added snapshot above and the restore command is      <Target Name="RESTOREPACKAGES">
   <DownloadNuGet OutputFilename="$(NuGetExePath)" Condition="!Exists('$(NuGetExePath)')" />
 <MSBuild  Projects="$(SolutionFileName)"  Targets="Restore"  Properties="VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);Configuration=$(Configuration)"/>
  </Target>